# Is it possible to create fields in a Matrix block from frontend?

Tags: plugin-development

My clients wants its restaurant owners to create FAQs from frontend where each owner can add its questions from frontend and the users will have to submit its answers. I thought to implement it through creating a matrix field which will be available for each restaurants entry. The name of the field could be the question and the text field could be the answer. Each users could save there answers to a new block. I know how to put data into matrix fields that are already made. But i can't find anything from which i can add fields in a matrix block. Is it even possible? Is there any type of plugin available which would help me in it? Any other ideas for this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lengthy rundown about this in [this ticket](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-do-you-create-a-front-end-form-for-users-to-submit-content) if you need a detailed explanation.

In short, you'll want to check out P&T's [Guest Entries plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries) to populate entries on the back-end from front-end input.

I highly suggest paying very close attention to how you should set up your form fields' `name` attributes from this StraightUpCraft post (scroll to the very bottom for Matrix fields): https://straightupcraft.com/articles/craft-cms-field-guide-twig?view=input